# Mod Rewrite Rule is changing the CWD in PHP - Why?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, working-directory

I have a strange problem that I can't find documentation for. I have a page at the following location in my server.

```
{SITE_ROOT}/admin/myfolder/myfile.php
```

This file uses an include to run a global configuration file which resides on the root of the server - it does this relative to itself

```
// {SITE_ROOT}/admin/myfolder/myfile.php
// includes {SITE_ROOT}/config.php    See below explanation after edit
include('../config.php);
```

This works fine UNTIL I add the following .htaccess file into the myfolder directory

```
// {SITE_ROOT}/admin/myfolder/.htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Z]+)\.gif$ gif_generator.php?gifid=$1 [L]
```

The purpose of this rule isn't important - the fact is that the page above (myfile.php) shouldn't be affected by this rule (it shouldn't match the regex unless I'm mistaken - and I might well be). Yet is seems that when this rule is being used, the include() inside myfile.php fails. It's as if the current working directory of the php file is changed by virtue of the RewriteEngine being enabled.

Is this documented anywhere and is there a way to prevent this from happening?

**edit** - I missed something rather important. The original file ({SITE_ROOT}/admin/myfolder/myfile.php) is itself being included by a file in the following location ({SITE_ROOT}/admin/frontcontroller.php). The include path in myfile.php is actually relative to *this* file. I've changed the above question to reflect this.

Comment: that rewrite rule doesn't match your url, so this doesn't make much sense.  Is that all that's in your .htaccess file?

Comment: @stephenbayer  - That's the whole file. There is another file in that directory that uses php to dynamically generate gif images - hence the rule.

Comment: @stephenbayer - Apologies - I missed a rather important bit of information in my original question. Now updated.

Comment: This does not make much sense to me: `include('/../config.php);` -- you have path starting with leading slash (which means ABSOLUTE path). http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: Instead of using such relative paths, use more solid approach: for `{SITE_ROOT}/config.php` use `include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/config.php');`

Comment: Hi @LazyOne, sorry for that - the leading slash was a mistake - it's not in the code. The path is relative. Unfortunately this is not brand spanking new code - I'm dealing with a legacy application that I need to support so I'm unable to change this. I agree that the way that it is done is poor. do you have any idea about the change in working directory (and why mod rewrite makes a difference) as that is the core issue here? - thanks. I'm going to put a test case (full code for download and local execution) together later which I'll post here

Comment: Unfortunately I have no bright ideas about why you having such behaviour -- I have never seen anything like that even when I was using relative paths myself (but I always have only one .htaccess file in website root folder).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is usefull to you:

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

returns the directory the file is in. So if you know the directory structure of your site you could use something like

```
dirname(dirname(__FILE__))
```

You can also use

```
DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
```

to get the directory separator specific to the server OS

In your case this would become

```
include(rtrim(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)),'/\\').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config.php')
```